# Adding to schema to ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, database-schema, azure-rm-template

I just created an ARM template to create Azure SQL server and Database.
Is there a way to add database schema to this existing ARM template?
If not, what will be the best course of action to specify schema for the resource created through this ARM template.

Answer (score 0):

ARM templates are only used to manage infrastructure resources themselves, not their content. To define the database schema, you will need to run SQL scripts against the database.

I'd recommend using migrations to generate those SQL scripts. While you haven't mentioned in which language the connected application is written, [here is documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) on migrations in .NET's Entity Framework Core